# Open several instances of the same application (e.g. Chrome) on three monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, productivity

Upon starting my PC with 3 monitors, I want to open 3 instances of a program, e.g. OneNote or Chrome on each monitor. Each instance should have a custom size/position on the monitor. How can I achieve that?

My OS is Windows 10. So far I've tried ZMover, which works, but only for one instance of an application.

Comment: I tried to reword your question so as not to fall under the rule of product-recommendation type questions, which are not encouraged. Please [edit] your post and give more information about your OS and which solutions you have already tried.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.

Comment: @slhck - OneNote sort of limits the scope to a Windows machine.

Comment: @Ramhound Where else should I seek help if not here then?

Comment: @Vladimir - There is a Stack Exchange website for software recommendations.  Be sure you read their help center, so your question meets their requirements.  You might also take a look at ours.